# Why do I get "400 Bad Request" when I switch my cloud load balancer to HTTPS?

Tags: kubernetes, https, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I have a K3s cluster using my hoster's (Hetzner) cloud controller manager and cloud load balancer. HTTP works fine and all I'm doing is adding the last 3 Traefik annotations for HTTPS.

```yaml
# /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/traefik-config.yaml
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChartConfig
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  valuesContent: |-
    additionalArguments:
      - --entryPoints.web.proxyProtocol.trustedIPs=10.0.2.1
      - --entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=10.0.2.1
    service:
      annotations:
        load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: worker-lb
        load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/use-private-ip: 'true'
        load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/protocol: https
        load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/certificate-type: managed
        load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/http-managed-certificate-domains: '*.example.org,example.org'
```

The CCM correctly generates the certificate and assigns it to the load balancer. Everything looks fine in the hoster's web UI. I can browse to the domain and HTTPS works.

The problem is that the response is now "400 Bad Request". Since I successfully get through to my cluster and get a certificate I think the error must be somewhere in my configuration.

When I delete/apply the ingress I sometimes see this error in the Traefik pod:

```
Error while updating ingress status: failed to update ingress status monitoring/monitoring: Operation cannot be fulfilled on ingresses.networking.k8s.io \"monitoring\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

My manifests:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: monitoring
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prometheus.example.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus
  ports:
  - name: prometheus
    port: 9090
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus
        image: prom/prometheus
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
```

Comment: Maybe it's expecting plain http while it encounters the encrypted https?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the UI the CCM configured the load balancer for TLS termination and not TLS passthrough.